# Phonegap CLI Exit Codes

Tags: cordova, exit-code

This [Phonegap blog post](http://phonegap.com/blog/2014/11/13/phonegap-cli-3-6-3/) explains that PG now supports exit codes. Typically a non-zero Phonegap CLI exit code, checked via `echo $?` means that there was a problem.  Helpful but not helpful enough if you do not know what the error code means.  I am running a Phonegap CLI command from a batch file and get `exit code 1`.  I have searched high and low but not found a list of exit codes and what they mean.  I am hoping that someone here will be able to point me to full list of exit codes + their meanings